# I am not able to write the script

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to print out a single value after print out the all the values. 
Print out all option code-

```
List<WebElement> li=  sel.getOptions();


    for(int i =0; i<li.size(); i++)
       {
         String value = li.get(i).getText();

         System.out.println(value);

       }
```

Below developer code.

```
<option value="339" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(199, 237, 215);">Bankura</option>
<option value="334" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(199, 237, 215);">Birbhum</option>
<option value="335" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(199, 237, 215);">Burdwan</option>
<option value="329" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(199, 237, 215);">Cooch Behar</option>
<option value="331" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(199, 237, 215);">Dakshin Dinajpur</option>
<option value="341" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(199, 237, 215);">Howrah</option>
<option value="336" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(199, 237, 215);">Nadia</option>
<option value="344" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(199, 237, 215);">Paschim Medinipur</option>
<option value="345" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(199, 237, 215);">Purba Medinipur</option>
```

Comment: ask your self this question, just by reading above information are you able to understand the question or not? if not how other person would be ?

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code by replacing your web element.

```
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("test")));
    List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();

    for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++){
        String currentValue = options.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println(currentValue);
    }
```

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: I am very sorry for my question.I know it is very difficult to answer my question.  In my first test script, Print out all the option from combo box. After that, I am trying to print out the option like- Burdwan. But i am not able to to do that. Please see the above code for your refenrence

Comment: Can you please tell me what exception you are getting by using this code. Then I can easily help you.

Comment: I am not able to write this code, where Burdwan option is print out. Please help me how to write this code.

Comment: @Arijit can you please specify what you are unable to write

Comment: First time, print out all the option name.Help of this code-List<WebElement> li=  sel.getOptions()
    for(int i =0; i<li.size(); i++)
       {
         String value = li.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println(value);

       }                                                                                                         Second time, just print out the Burdwan option. how to write this code.

Comment: What I understand is first time you want to print all the options then you want to print out one at a time is that correct?

Comment: What ever code that I provided Is that printing all the options one by one?

Comment: Right@ Akrash. I am just print out Single option like 'Burdwan', After print out all the option. You please provide after print out all the option with my above code and then print out the Single option 'Burdwan'.